# Can we just say "I am pulling up" instead of "I am doing pull-up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Ok,

> **pull-up**: an exercise in which you hold onto a high bar above your head
>   and pull yourself up towards it [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pull-up_1)

Ex: "*I am doing pull-ups*"

> **to pull up**: (of a vehicle or its driver) to stop.  [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pull-up_2)

Ex: "*He pulled up at the traffic lights*".

so, the dictionary has no verb "**to pull up**" meaning "*to do an exercise in which you hold onto a high bar above your head and pull yourself up towards it*"

Without worrying about dictionary,

Can we just say "*I am pulling up*" instead of "*I am doing pull-ups*"?

Comment: In a word, no. As the dictionary says, it means something different.

Comment: Also, it would be "I am doing pull-ups"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"To pull up" is taken to literally mean "to pull something else upwards", whereas "a pull-up" is a specific kind of exercise that someone performs. The big difference being that the concept of "doing" an exercise implies a repeated action, while simply "pulling up" implies doing it once.

So, for the same reason that you don't say "I am pushing up" instead of "I am doing push-ups", or "I am squatting" instead of "I am doing squats", you cannot say "I am pulling up" instead of "I am doing pull-ups".